# recording total runtime in bash script

Tags: bash, debian, shell-script

I have the following script. When it runs it prints the `Start` and `end` Times to the file 'result.txt'.

However, I also want to record the total runtime (`end-start`), but where I am doing `echo runtine` at the end, it just returns `runtime:` with nothing recorded next to it. Am I doing something incorrect?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Test 001" > result.txt
echo "start time: " $(date +%T) >> result.txt
start=`date +%s`
#DO STUFF HERE
end=`date +%s`
echo "end time: " $(date +%T) >> result.txt
runtime=$((end-start))
echo "runtime: " $(runtime) >> result.txt
echo " - - - "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are reinventing the wheel. That's what the `time` command is for:

```
$ time script.sh
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Then, you have a syntax error:

```
echo "runtime: " $(runtime) >> result.txt
```

The `$(foo)` syntax is command substitution, it will try to run `foo`. What you meant was

```
 echo "runtime: $runtime" >> result.txt
```

By the way, you should always include the error messages you get in your question.

Comment: cheers, that makes sense. I didn't use `time` as I wanted the result stored in the file. Also, I didn't get any error messages (not that I saw anyway).

Comment: @IGGt you can still use `time`, just use a subshell: `( time script.sh ) 2> log.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your echo statement. It should be

```
#!/bin/bash
#clear
echo "Test 001" > result.txt
echo "start time: " $(date +%T) >> result.txt
start=`date +%s`
#DO STUFF HERE
end=`date +%s`
echo "end time: " $(date +%T) >> result.txt
runtime=$((end-start))
echo "runtime: $runtime" >> result.txt
echo " - - - "
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: @PandaLion98 haha...sorry about that :)

Comment: Take an upvote.